# Rails 4.x ETAG with S3 assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, caching, amazon-s3, etag

I'm working on enabling cache on my Rails app. I enabled ETAG on a action, and it's working great. But some of the user assets are in a S3 bucket, like the profile picture. So after a few minutes, the amazon url expires and the page doesn't find the profile picture anymore.

How to handle something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find out. The only way to solve this is making the profile picture public, without expiring time.